# Anyway to shorten code inside if statement JavaScript

Tags: javascript, button

Is there a way to shorten the code inside the if statement in JavaScript I'm thinking for loop but I don't know how and if it's even possible. I already put the what I think the relevant code

```js
var operators = document.querySelectorAll(".operators button");
var string = screenInput.innerHTML
var lastCharacter = string[string.length - 1]
console.log(lastCharacter)

if (lastCharacter === "+") {
  document.getElementById("subtract-operator").disabled = true
  document.getElementById("multiply-operator").disabled = true
  document.getElementById("divide-operator").disabled = true
}
```

```html
<div class="operators">
  <button id="add-operator">+</button>
  <button id="subtract-operator">-</button>
  <button id="multiply-operator">*</button>
  <button id="divide-operator">/</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there only this one `if` statement, or are there statements for each operator (to disable the other operator buttons)?

Comment: Yeah, there are other if statements the same as above

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Rory on the loop, but it looks as though the code was meant to disable the buttons not used in the current operation. So if the `+` button is pressed, the other buttons are disabled and the `+` button is left enabled.

If this is the case, you can assign the `disabled` property based on the condition. And if you are looping through the buttons, you can just grab the `innerText` property to compare against your `lastCharacter` variable.

```
let lastCharacter = screenInput.innerHTML.substr(-1)
document.querySelectorAll(".operators button").forEach(b => {
  b.disabled = (b.innerText !== lastCharacter)
})
```

Comment: I deleted my answer as this is a far better and more extensible approach

Answer (score 0):

we can do the inverse logic like this:

*"select all except this one."*

maybe using a CSS solution `:not()` will be useful https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not

to not repeat always the same button ids, but just the ones you don't want to use.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".operators button")
      .querySelectorAll(":not(#add-operator)") // filtering the ids: ❌ #add-operator, ✅ #subtract-operator, ✅ #multiply-operator, ✅ #divide-operator
      .forEach((elem) => elem.disabled = true);
```